# Domain-Driven Design Confusion

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am learning DDD concepts and to strengthen my understanding I am working on some real world examples.

I know that an aggregate should have only one entry point through the root entity and an aggregate should have only one repository (please correct me if I understood it totally wrong)

Now assume that there are consumables with specific types and these consumables are sent from a distribution center. Sending specific types of consumables depends on their quantity, I mean if one of the consumers has a critic quantity 10 for type A and B and those item quantities fall under 10 then the distribution center sends type A and B consumables. Here both the sender and consumer wants to track where the sent package is or if it is delivered or sent at all.

So here, as entities, we have:

1. Consumable
2. ConsumableType
3. ConsumableActivity
4. Package
5. PackageItem
6. Consumer

I am confused about the first three entities: which one should be the aggregate root? In a fast look it seems that the consumable is a strong candidate but on the other hand we do not care about every consumable, we are only interested in their quantity. We don't record 10 different type A consumables but only have a type A record with quantity which changes according to activities. At this point Consumable entity seems redundant, by just looking at activities we can derive the quantity. For example starting from scratch:

1. Center Create "Type A" 10
2. Center Create "Type B" 20
3. Center Send "Type A" 5 ConsumerId=25
4. Center Send "Type B" 15 ConsumerId=25
5. ConsumerId=25 Receive "Type A" 5
6. ConsumerId=25 Receive "Type B" 15
7. ConsumerId=25 Consume "Type A" 3
8. ConsumerId=25 Consume "Type B" 1
9. ConsumerId=25 Consume "Type A" 2

Here we can derive that there are 5 Type A and B consumables at the center and 0 Type A, 14 Type B consumables at consumer with id 25 for now.

Of course this is not an effective approach while after there are much more activities it will take some time to derive consumable quantities, so there should be a static quantity field for every consumable type both for consumers and the distribution center in which we can read the current quantity at once.

I hope you get why I am confused, the consumable entity looks like a root entity but actually it doesn't really fit in to be a root entity if not an entity also.

Can anyone suggest me some improvements about this design or and further reading recommendations which are not limited to customer-product-order-orderline nightmare?

---

Edit : What is the relation with Consumable and ConsumableType ? What if I want to conduct CRUD operations on ConsumableType (to make the user add new types, change or delete them) but the root entity is Consumable. In order to DDD to preserve data integrity we should't load any repository other than the root entity repository.

Edit 2: Think about a Product entity and its Category entity. The Product seems to be the root entity but we know that products cannot exist without a category. So is the Category entity the root? If so, according to DDD rules, we can access products only by traversing. But in our context the Product is our focus. Then it is supposed that we have two aggregates: Product Aggregate and Category Aggregate. But this time we violate the data integrity because a category may be deleted without deleting products having this category. So I am confused a lot and couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: First, your expressed problem of "both the sender and consumer wants to track where the sent package is or if it is delivered or sent at all" implies two different contexts.  Second, both contexts seems to suggest that package is your aggregate that you "build" using consumerables at the center and then "ship" to the customer who then "recieves" it, "unpackages" and, possibly, "consumes" it. The quotes are to denote domain actions.  Does this seem correct based on your current understanding of the problem domain?

Comment: It is totally correct but I forgot to say that there is one more entity which is "special consumable". This actually does not inherit from **consumable** because when it is produced it is related with some **consumer** so it is sent to and consumed by only that specific consumer. Hence a package can include **consumable**, **special consumable** or both. Also an activity record is important for **consumable** and **special consumable** .

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but I will note that, from your example, ConsumableType sounds more like a value object than an entity.  Also, if I may make a presumptuous suggestion, I would verify your ubiquitous language. Are Consumable, Consumable Activity, and Package Item the terms the domain experts use?

Comment: Well, while its all fictional I can say yes, these are domain experts use. We can conduct CRUD operations on **ConsumableType** and it can exist without a **Consumable** so it is not a value object.

Comment: Having CRUD operations for a concept does not make it an entity. Also, value objects can exist without an association with an entity. Think Currencies, Colors...

Comment: In resp. to your edits, you are thinking like a programmer. It can be hard to take off our programmer hat and put on our BA hat, but you need to when modelling the domain. Forget about your preconceptions of parent-child relationships and only model the relationships that exist in the eyes of your domain experts.  For example, in the case of products/categories, categories are generally value objects that are assigned to a product (even if you have a hierarchy of categories). Just because it has an id in the db doesn't mean it has an id to the domain expert and here, it's really just a value.

Comment: @moranlf so what if domain experts think that -lets say- they want to add more colors anytime, change their names and delete them? And again what happens that they state that an item must have a color. In this case is the Color still a value object or an entity outside the Item aggregate with its own services, repository and factory?

Comment: @AaronHawkins yes you are right, trying to think outside the box is really hard. I only want to understand where type like, attribute like, category like and etc. like classes such as category-product item-itemtype, customer-customertype fits in CRM or CMS applications. Because while in most of applications domain experts do not mention those specifically and are simple look-ups or constants, especially in CRM or CMS applications they have a special focus. For example as moranlf mentioned Color, it is obviously a value object but in a CMS system it may be an entity, so where does Color fit?

Comment: Is there ever a case where you need to differentiate between two color objects that have the same blue value, even in a CMS system?  Just because it has an ID (#0000FF) doesn't mean there is a distinction to your domain experts.  As a user, if I choose blue as my font color, I am only picking the value of blue.  In this situation, FontBrush is also a value object with various sub-values that I have chosen.  Now, what if the CMS system allows me to name and save various brush configurations?  All of a sudden the FontBrush becomes an entity with an identity (name).

Comment: Just remember that what makes an entity an entity is its identity. For example, Color may be an entity in a Paint-mixer application. Maybe, when mixing paint, the type of paint determines how a color will be transformed when mixed.  In this situation, you might have a Color entity with a value of paint type, values for the color, and a name or part number (identity) that the domain expert uses to distinguish between the blue of one paint type and the same blue in another paint type. So the aggregate might be called like: Mixer.MixPaint(type1OilBlue,type2OilBlue);

Comment: @AaronHawkins in your first case, how can, for example a system administrator, list all available font colors or add a new one? Should he/she traverse over all fonts and their color values and take a distinct set of them? What if there is a blue color code but no font uses it yet?

Comment: By the way you better move your comment to a answer so I can select them as an answer :) thanks.

Comment: Agree with "Just remember that what makes an entity an entity is its identity."  Also useful, I think, is to think of the identity as a key in _key space_, that is managed by one of the business roles (who has the authority and responsibility for new keys, e.g. adding an SKU or product code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused about the first three entities: which one should be the
>   aggregate root?

I am going to say that, most likely, your aggregate is Package even though there is the possibility that this example should be split into two or more separate bounded contexts. (creation and order fulfillment are natural boundaries)

> What is the relation with Consumable and ConsumableType ?

It depends on your bounded context.  Without knowing any more about ConsumableType other than it is designated by "A" or "B", I would have to say that it is more than likely a value object of Consumable.

> What if I want to conduct CRUD operations on ConsumableType (to make
>   the user add new types, change or delete them) but the root entity is
>   Consumable

This is most likely a different bounded context altogether (context of some manager or something that doesn't fall within the general workflow we're modeling) for which more investigation about this context is suggested.

**[Different Example]**

> So is the Category entity the root?

The aggregate root is what the user in the context interacts with.  Assuming ALOT because you don't fully explain the context in this example, most likely the Product is the aggregate root because that is what the user cares most about.  Same as the above example, Product would have a repository that would load it's assigned category to it.  Loading the list of categories or hierarchy is best served by a domain service in this case because it doesn't belong to any particular entity instance.

**[Another Example]**

> in your first case, how can, for example a system administrator, list
>   all available font colors or add a new one?

Again, the context of a system administrator is not the same context as the user who chooses the font color.  Remember, each context is a single workflow.  In complex workflows, there can be multiple users in the same context, but for the simple workflows like the CRUD operations an administrator might perform, generally there is only one role for this type of workflow.  Under the system administrator, AvailableFontColor might be an entity with a Color value property within the Content Decoration Options Administration bounded context.

> Can anyone suggest me some improvements about this design or and
>   further reading recommendations which are not limited to
>   customer-product-order-orderline nightmare?

I would suggest that you learn more about bounded contexts and why they are one of your most useful (and most hampering at times) tools in modeling a business domain.  Also, don't expect to have this perfected to a science within a week.

I have been modeling software using various techniques for over 8 years now and there are still times where I have trouble deciding if I modeled something correctly or not.  I think one of the greatest benefits of DDD is that it encourages you to embrace the fact that you probably won't model correctly from the beginning so you should make it easy to change the model and refactor often as you learn more about your domain rather than just going with what you have and ending up with 15 different convoluted cludges around your original model because you didn't fully understand the domain from the beginning.